# Auto Renew Letsencrypt on Cloudpanel using Cron Job

Tags: lets-encrypt

I installed cloudpanel on ubuntu, but I can't find the automatic renewal option for SSL (letsencrypt), the only option is through cron jobs
I searched but didn't find anything about how to do this.

Which command should I add to automatically renew the certificate every month in cron jobs?
The panel looks like this:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0HKl.png)

Answer (score 1):

According to [Cloudpanel](https://www.cloudpanel.io/), you don't need a cron job as it renews certificates automatically. Just make a Let's Encrypt request for your domain at once, then let CloudPanel do the rest for you.

> Install Let’s Encrypt SSL certificates in one click for free! Automatically deploy and renew for multiple domains and subdomains.